# failed to open stream and helper data not found in module

Tags: magento-1.4

Im using this module: AdjustWare_Giftreg in magento 1.4
The page is not showing all the products.
the module is active=false but is still showing just one product.

this are the logs:

- Warning: include(Mage/Adjgiftreg/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in..
- Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Adjgiftreg/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion

My files:

> > app/etc/modules/AdjustWare_Giftreg.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
       <modules>
    <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <self_name>Gift Registry</self_name>
        <priority>70</priority>
    </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
</modules>
```

> > app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config>
         <modules>
    <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <adjgiftreg>
            <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>adjgiftreg_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </adjgiftreg>
        <adjgiftreg_mysql4>
            <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <event>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_event</table>
                </event>
                <item>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_item</table>
                </item>
                <thank>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_thank</table>
                </thank>
                <order>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_order</table>
                </order>
                <type>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_type</table>
                </type>
                <type_title>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_type_title</table>
                </type_title>
                <item_option>
                    <table>adjgiftreg_item_option</table>
                </item_option>
            </entities>
        </adjgiftreg_mysql4>

        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <type_onepage>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Rewrite_FrontCheckoutTypeOnepage</type_onepage>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>    
        <downloadable>
            <rewrite>
                <observer>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Rewrite_DownloadableObserver</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </downloadable>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <adjgiftreg_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </adjgiftreg_setup>
        <adjgiftreg_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </adjgiftreg_write>
        <adjgiftreg_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </adjgiftreg_read>
    </resources>
    <template>
        <email>
            <adjgiftreg_email_share translate="label" module="adjgiftreg">
                <label>Gift Registry - Share </label>
                <file>adjgiftreg_share.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </adjgiftreg_email_share>
            <adjgiftreg_email_notification translate="label" module="adjgiftreg">
                <label>Gift Registry - System Notification</label>
                <file>adjgiftreg_admin_notification.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </adjgiftreg_email_notification>
        </email>
    </template> 

    <blocks>
        <adjgiftreg>
            <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block</class>
        </adjgiftreg>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_edit_tabs>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_AdminhtmlCustomerEditTabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                <sales_order_view>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_AdminhtmlView</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_FrontCheckoutOnepageShipping</onepage_shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>


    <helpers>
        <adjgiftreg>
            <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper</class>
        </adjgiftreg>

        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <data>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Rewrite_CheckoutData</data>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </helpers>

    <events>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processCartAddProductComplete</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>

        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processCartProductAdd</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

        <sales_quote_remove_item>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processCartProductRemoved</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_remove_item>

        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processBeforeOrderSaved</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>

        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processAfterOrderSaved</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>

        <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>processCartUpdated</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
        <sales_quote_merge_before>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>mergeQuotes</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_merge_before>

        <aitoc_module_disable_before>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/moduleObserver</class>
                    <method>onAitocModuleDisableBefore</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </aitoc_module_disable_before> 

        <aitoc_editablecart_product_add>
            <observers>
                <adjgiftreg>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                    <method>onEditablecartProductAdd</method>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </observers>
        </aitoc_editablecart_product_add> 

    </events>
</global>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <adjgiftreg_expire_event>
            <!-- each day-->
            <schedule><cron_expr>2 2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>adjgiftreg/observer::expireEvents</model></run>
        </adjgiftreg_expire_event>

    </jobs> 
</crontab> 


 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <adjgiftreg>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
                <frontName>gifts</frontName>
            </args>
        </adjgiftreg>
    </routers>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
                <files>
                    <default>AdjustWare_Giftreg.csv</default>
                </files>
            </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
        </modules>
    </translate>
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <adjgiftreg module="AdjustWare_Giftreg">
                  <file>adjgiftreg.xml</file>
              </adjgiftreg>
          </updates>
      </layout>
</frontend>   

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adjgiftregadmin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
                <frontName>adjgiftregadmin</frontName>
            </args>
        </adjgiftregadmin>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <customer>
            <children>
                <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                    <title>Gift Registries</title>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                            <title>Registries</title>
                            <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_event</action>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </registries>
                        <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                            <title>Event Types</title>
                            <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_type</action>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        </types>
                    </children>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </children>
        </customer>
    </menu> 

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <adjgiftreg translate="title">
                                <title>Gift Registries</title>
                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                        <title>Registries</title>
                                    </registries>
                                    <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                        <title>Event Types</title>
                                    </types>
                                </children>
                            </adjgiftreg>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                                        <title>Gift Registries Section</title>
                                    </adjgiftreg>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system> 
                 </children>
            </admin> 
        </resources>
    </acl>

    <translate>
        <modules>
            <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
                <files>
                    <default>AdjustWare_Giftreg.csv</default>
                </files>
            </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml> 

<default>
    <adjgiftreg>
       <general>
            <active>0</active>
            <qty_warning>1</qty_warning>
            <secure>0</secure>
            <scope>0</scope>
        </general>
        <email>
            <share_identity>general</share_identity>
            <share>adjgiftreg_email_share</share>

            <notification_enable>1</notification_enable>
            <notification_identity>general</notification_identity>
            <notification>adjgiftreg_email_notification</notification>
            <notification_recipient><![CDATA[admin@example.com]]></notification_recipient>
        </email> 
    </adjgiftreg>
</default>
```

> > app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
        <menu>
        <customer>
            <children>
                <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                    <title>Gift Registries</title>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                            <title>Registries</title>
                            <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_event</action>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </registries>
                        <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                            <title>Event Types</title>
                            <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_type</action>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        </types>
                    </children>
                </adjgiftreg>
            </children>
        </customer>
    </menu> 

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <adjgiftreg translate="title">
                                <title>Gift Registries</title>
                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                        <title>Registries</title>
                                    </registries>
                                    <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                        <title>Event Types</title>
                                    </types>
                                </children>
                            </adjgiftreg>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                                        <title>Gift Registries Section</title>
                                    </adjgiftreg>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system> 
                 </children>
            </admin> 
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Comment: This problem came when you install your new module while compilation enable

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this

1) First way is to solve this is to run compilation process under system->tools->compilation.

2) in other way You need to create **AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Data.php** in includes/src folder which is at the root folder this file will coantain all the code of helper class of your custom module.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer Ramkshan..I have this in my AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Data.php: class_exists("Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action"); require_once "/var/www/html/domain/subdomains/v1/app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/Helper/Data.php";    i replace with all the content of the class AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract, But i have the same error

Comment: You didn't get me @Leoh  I have said that you need to create file in indule/src but not to delete or replace helper class in your custom module.

Comment: After that one thing you can do is to disable compilation from backed.

Comment: i already had AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Data.php but the problem is that i changed my hosting and Magento died after compilation because of the new paths. How could i change the path for complilate again with the new paths of modules and requires